# Apache fraction exception: "The fraction to divide by must not be zero"

Tags: android, eclipse, apache

```
E/AndroidRuntime(878): Caused by: org.apache.commons.math3.exception.MathArithmeticException: the fraction to divide by must not be zero: 0/1
```

The line the error happens is this one:

```
flist1.get(x).set(y, flist1.get(x).get(y).divide(z));
```

But, I have an if statement right before that line saying:

```
if(!flist1.get(x).get(y).equals(new Fraction(0)))
```

So I see no possible way for the "fraction to divide" to be zero as the if statement prevents it.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because your `z` variable must be 0.